# How to stop play framework from Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need to check if some conditions are correct before starting-up a Play server. I do that in my `Global` class by overriding the `onStart` method.

However I want to stop the Play server if the `onStart` method detects all conditions are not correct.

Is there a better way to do that instead of using a `System.exit()`?

After having looked for an answer, I read about the existence of `Play.stop()`. However:

- it is not described in the [documentation of Play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/Play.html)
- I have access to a `play.api.Play` class with the `stop()` method, but the [`play.api` package is not referenced in the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html), and it does nothing.

Any ideas? Or should I stop thinking and use `System.exit()`?

Answer (score 1):

- `System.exit(1)` seems to be good way for graceful ending the instance, especially right after
- semi-package `api` is representation of Scala methods so you should check [Scala API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Play%24) instead for this
- Optionally you can try to read `RUNNING_PID` file from within your Global class and just kill the process with given PID (didn't try it, but that's the way how `play` script stops the instance when using `play stop` command)